# DropDown not render in UI Grid angular js

Tags: angularjs

My view have below code section but when user click on cell edit option is avilable but in textbox instead-of dropdown list:

```
 <div id="grdAreaDetails" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit></div>
```

**And controller is below**

```
 $scope.cellSelectEditableTemplate = '<select  ng-model="COL_FIELD" ><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option></select>';

$scope.maxLength = 200;
$scope.sites = [];
$scope.showloadingdiv = true;
$scope.isAreaAddPanelHide = false;

$scope.gridOptions = {};

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [                 
{
    name: 'code', field: 'code', enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    editableCellTemplate: $scope.cellSelectEditableTemplate
},
{ name: 'name',field:'name'},
{ name: 'notes',field:'notes'},
{ name: 'description', field: 'description' },
 { name: 'siteid', field: 'siteid' },
{ name: 'status',field:'status' }
];

$scope.gridOptions = {      
    data: $scope.AreaRecord,
    multiSelect: false,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.UpdateArea);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove  enableCellEditOnFocus: true and add " enableCellSelection: true" 
And let me know what happens.

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [                 
 {
   name: 'code', field: 'code' , enableCellSelection: true,
   editableCellTemplate: $scope.cellSelectEditableTemplate
 },
 { name: 'name',field:'name'},
 { name: 'notes',field:'notes'},
 { name: 'description', field: 'description' },
 { name: 'siteid', field: 'siteid' },
 { name: 'status',field:'status' }
];
```

If this doesn't work then make fiddle.